# An .net core console project "An assembly with the same identity has already been imported"

Tags: c#, entity-framework, visual-studio, .net-core-rc2

I just created simple .net core console project using visual studio for mac. And the sdk is .NET Core 1.1 SDK. After I installed Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.sqlite successfully，it just show me 12 errors, saying "An assembly  with the same identity has already been imported". But I still can't figure out which part should be removed.
The errors is this:

[image: this]
Thanks！

Comment: Just so you know, .Net 1.1 doesn't run on any modern version of Windows.   Why are you bringing that in?

Comment: @user1895086 Sorry，I mean .Net core

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for this dumb question, just following the error message and remove duplicate packages，and everything gonna be fine.